# Why does getTimer return an int, as opposed to uint, or even Number?

Tags: actionscript-3

This has confused and bugged me for a few years, thought I would open a discussion for it. Some questions to consider:

What are the performance implications for each data type?

Should I do all timestamp-related math with ints instead of uints?

What happens when getTimer goes above int.MAX_VALUE?

Comment: 2^31 milliseconds = 24.8551348 days

Comment: and then it would probably roll over to `-(2^31+1)` and then start incrementing again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any "real" evidence to back me up here, but I think they did it because, in the event the timer ever DID roll over, you can detect this and account for it accordingly. When a uint timer would roll over, it would be harder to detect.

Comment: Okay, it seems obvious now. I've even found myself using this feature - you can use -1 as a flag for "no time" or "indefinitely" or similar. Thanks for the answer

Comment: An int rolls over much earlier than a uint though (half the time) so in the end the result is the same, only that with ints you need to detect so earlier. For reference, in `getTimer()`, an int rolls over after ~596 hours, an uint in ~1192.